# Css "card" article below to another one - Don't find the solution

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

First thanks for your time :)

i want to create article one below the other, card's css styling. But i don't find solution to my problem.

i've tried to use z-index, absolute and relative position, clear:both and float etc..

But i can't find the solution

Here is a screen of what i want to do :

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5135/RkjGbs.jpg

Here the result i want to get also:

https://demos.creative-tim.com/hipster-as-f-cards/presentation.html?_ga=2.266266695.990224034.1554927522-1333580824.1554927522&fbclid=IwAR3J0ZiT_HQ3G30UZEnfCCND74IvKWwcaF3MzyYQx6YZmmo5LPDVwpbsC8w

I've also checked in the code, but it seems to complex for me.

here is the part of the html/CSS code concerned :

```css
/* font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Raleway');

body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}

a:hover {text-decoration: none}


.haute {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 10vw;
}


.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 9vw;
  width: 9vw;

}

.logo-title {
  margin-left: 5vw;
}
.title {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}

.navigation a{
   display: inline;
   float: right;
   margin-left: 1vw;
   font-size: 1.5vw;
   margin-top: 5vw;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;

}

.navigation-div {
  margin-right : 5vw;
}

/* carousel */

.carousel {
  height: 20vw;
}



.carousel-item {
    height: 20vw;
}


/* end carousel */

/* structure */

.suite {

  margin-top: 2vw;


}
.aside {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50vw;
}

.portfolio {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50vw;
}


.footer {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  height: 10vw;
}


/* Portfolio */

.row-margin {
  margin-right: 9vw;
  margin-left: 9vw;
}





/* Le contenu des cartes */

/* artcile card */

.citation-card {

  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  display: block;


}

.citation-img {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  box-shadow : 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.article-card {
  height: 35vw;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5vw 0.5vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow : 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.article-card h2 {
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: black;

}

.article-card h3 {
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  color: #798081;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.article-card p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #798081;
}

.article-card-img {
  height: 15vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0 0 ;
}


/* article sound card */

.article-card-sound {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0 0 ;
}

.article-card-sound-div {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 20vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow : 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw ;
  position: relative;
}

.article-card-sound-div h2 {
  position : absolute;
  color: #000010;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5vw;
}

.play-icon {

  position : absolute;
  margin-top: 30vw;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  text-shadow: 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw #ffffff;

}

.play-icon:hover {
  color: #A9A9A9;
}

.audio-player {
    width: 20vw;
    position : absolute;
    margin-top: 37vw;
}

/* just article card */

.article-card-just-article {
  height: 17vw;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5vw 0.5vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow : 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.article-card-just-article h2 {
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: black;

}

.article-card-just-article h3 {
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  color: #798081;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.article-card-just-article p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #798081;

/* footer */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid suite">
<div class="row row-margin">


<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="citation-card">
  <img class="citation-img" src="img/citation-11.png" alt="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="article-card">
  <img class="article-card-img" src="img/4.jpg" alt="">

  <h3> News </h3>
  <h2> Titre article </h2>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="article-card-sound-div">
  <h2> Votre méditation guidées matinale </h2>
  <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x play-icon "></i>


  <img class="article-card-sound" src="img/meditation.jpg" alt="">

</div>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="article-card-just-article">

  <h3> News </h3>
  <h2> Titre article </h2>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  </p>
</div>
</div>




</div>

</div>
```

I expect my card to be below the other one as shown in the picture I've put.
I want to repeat the process for another article's "cards" as in the link i've put in example.The responsive seems to work now with these few cards, and i want a responsive solution if possible for the other cards also if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I see this question has a `jquery` tag, but no jQuery was found in the example. Is that something essential to creating the functionality you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to Bootstrap, you can do something like this:
https://codepen.io/artursden/pen/dRWeBw

Basically, you just need to re-organize your html, using only 3 col-* elements and put all the cards for each column inside them:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 masonry-column">
    [all cards for the first column go here]
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 masonry-column">
    [all cards for the second column go here]
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 masonry-column">
    [all cards for the third column go here]
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is that it might look awkward for certain screen sizes (if you define 3 columns and for certain sizes the take 50% of the width, the other column will be displayed below).

An alternative would be defining only 2 columns but, still, I believe the following are a better approach (CSS only):

[Pure CSS Masonry Layout](https://codepen.io/AdamBlum/pen/fwrnE)

This is a CSS-only solution (no Bootstrap or other dependencies required) using [CSS Multi-column Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) -widely supported in [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=column-width).

---

Also useful: [Approaches for a CSS Masonry Layout](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/)

Comment: Thanks  for the the quickness and the pertinence of your answer. I'll try this out :) again, thank you